# Integrate twitter to IPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth, mgtwitterengine

I am hoping to integrate Twitter to my application. My project is created with `ARC` support. When i added the Twitter framework i also flagged the .m files with `-fno-objc-arc`.

I could login to twitter (meaning, the authentication process works), and after the authentication that application crashes when i click the tweet button.

1.) This is what gets called first, twitter authentication works fine.

```
-(void)loginTwitterUser{
    if(_engine) return;


    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];  
    _engine.consumerKey = @"xxxxxx";
    _engine.consumerSecret = @"xxxxxx";

    if (![_engine isAuthorized]) {
        UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];
        if (controller) {
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }

    }
```

- `_engine` - i have declared this is the `.h` file, but did not synthesize it in the `.m`

  1. This is where we are going to tweet

     ```
     -(void)tweetThis:(id)sender{
     [_engine sendUpdate:@"Tweet something"];
     }
     ```

3.) other delagate methods

```
#pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterEngineDelegate
- (void) storeCachedTwitterOAuthData: (NSString *) data forUsername: (NSString *) username {
    NSUserDefaults   *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: data forKey: @"authData"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (NSString *) cachedTwitterOAuthDataForUsername: (NSString *) username {

    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"authData"];
}


#pragma mark TwitterEngineDelegate
- (void) requestSucceeded: (NSString *) requestIdentifier {

    NSLog(@"Request %@ succeeded", requestIdentifier);
}

- (void) requestFailed: (NSString *) requestIdentifier withError: (NSError *) error {

    NSLog(@"Request %@ failed with error: %@", requestIdentifier, error);
}

#pragma mark SA_OAuthTwitterController Delegate
```

**In the NSLog `username` is `null`. Why is this ?**

```
- (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username {

    NSLog(@"Authenticated with user %@", username);

}


- (void) OAuthTwitterControllerFailed: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller  {

    NSLog(@"Authentication Failure");
}

- (void) OAuthTwitterControllerCanceled: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller {

    NSLog(@"Authentication Canceled");
}
```

The application crashes in the `MGTwitterEngine.m` at the return statement.

```
- (NSString *)sendUpdate:(NSString *)status inReplyTo:(unsigned long)updateID
{
    if (!status) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"statuses/update.%@", API_FORMAT];

    NSString *trimmedText = status;
    if ([trimmedText length] > MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
        trimmedText = [trimmedText substringToIndex:MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    [params setObject:trimmedText forKey:@"status"];
    if (updateID > 0) {
        [params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", updateID] forKey:@"in_reply_to_status_id"];
    }
    NSString *body = [self _queryStringWithBase:nil parameters:params prefixed:NO];

    return [self _sendRequestWithMethod:HTTP_POST_METHOD path:path 
                        queryParameters:params body:body 
                            requestType:MGTwitterUpdateSendRequest
                           responseType:MGTwitterStatus];
}
```

How can i resolve this ?

Comment: which framework are you using? native iOS or third party?

Comment: What is the crash error?

Comment: The twitter library i used http://www.vivianaranha.com/TwitterLib.zip

Comment: I am also getting the same error.
Earlier, it was working fine, now crashing in this delegate method: 

-(void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username 
{
 NSLog(@"Authenicated for %@", username);
}

Comment: @Piyush have you try retaining the delegate ? Is _engine declared with `@property` ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless, No, I didn't retain the delegate. I didn't set property for _engine.

Comment: @Piyush, try doing it by declaring it with `@property` attribute. It happens to me sometimes that the delegate lost before the response comes due to delay in receiving response.

Comment: @NeverHopeless, ok. let me try. Will revert back.

Comment: @NeverHopeless, no, Not working.

Comment: What is not working ? do you get `controller = nil` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.m and try to implement the changes below. You should change http to https.

```
- (SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *) initOAuthWithDelegate: (NSObject *) delegate {
if (self = (id) [super initWithDelegate: delegate]) 
    {
        self.requestTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
        self.accessTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
        self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for you to do that, twitter integration has been optimized.

Check this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5

Comment: This will not work with iOS 4. I need it to work for both iOS 4 and 5