# How to integrate twitter to my iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

i need to integrate Twitter to my iPhone application. I have tried many 3rd party SDks, but non worked since i have enabled ARC to my project.

1.) So i need to know if there's a Native Twitter API which will be owned by Twitter it self ?
2.) I have tried sharekit, but may i know if there's other 3rd party APIs that i could use to integrate twitter for my application.

**note**: It should work for both iOS 4.3 and above. Also do not say this question is duplicated (i have looked at other questions but didn't find a solution to my problem yet) :)

i have already looked at [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#objectivec).

Comment: Have you searched about it on Google? There are couple of tutorial present there. You might use following - http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/09/integrating-twitter-into-your-applications/

Comment: ARC shouldn't negatively affect the functionality of an older library. Simply disable it for the library's files as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: Well, i did that. i had a different problem with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762765/integrate-twitter-to-iphone-application . I didn't find a solution for that problem, so now i am looking for a better API

Comment: So Is there a solution for this ? help i am still stuck with this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sharekit, be sure to be using sharekit 2.0, it has compatibility with iOS 5.
I recommend you ShareKit because it has a lot of other functionalities that may be useful for you, if you change your mind and give sharekit a second chance, just ask me and I will try to help you.

Also, if you have the ARC activated, I think your application won't have compatibility with iOS 4.3, so think about it. In case you insist in using ARC with 3rd party SDKs, just remove all the "retain", "release" and other expressions that are not allowed with it. XCode will tell you which expressions are not available with ARC.

Comment: Well, i think ARC is compatible with iOS 4.2 and above. (Need to clarify, now i am scared!). I use the flag to disable ARC which i think is the equivalent of removing the retains and releases. ShareKit has about 60 .m files and i have to remove all release/retains in it :( and Is there any tutorial that will demonstrate how to integrate Twitter using sharekit for iOS ?

Comment: Of course there is, actually, it is VERY SIMPLE =D here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432297/iphone-how-to-use-sharekit-only-to-post-to-facebook-or-only-to-twitter <<< for Twitter is the same as facebook, just use the SHKTwitter Class instead of the SHKTwitter class. Also, be sure to add your API Key and those things in the configuration file.